# Выровнять по ширине flex items

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: http://i.imgur.com/7aHqYNz.png]

Изменяется ширина между блоками(цифра 1).Нужно что бы размер между блоками был фиксирован, а размер между текстом и блоком(цифра 2) увеличивался, ну и как в примере на всю ширину контейнера

```css
.flex-container {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-around;
}
.flex-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #826088;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: "RobotoLight";
  color: #000000;
  height: 39px;
  font-size: 16.05px;
  /* Приближение из-за подстановки шрифтов */
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.72);
}
.flex-item2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-sm-12">


  <ul class="flex-container">
    <li style="  background-image: url(http://cs7004.vk.me/v7004757/2316a/XUww5gs_jXE.jpg);" class="flex-item2">
      <div class="flex-item">Распродажа</div>
    </li>
    <li style="  background-image: url(http://cs7004.vk.me/v7004757/2316a/XUww5gs_jXE.jpg);" class="flex-item2">
      <div class="flex-item">Новинки</div>
    </li>
    <li style="  background-image: url(http://cs7004.vk.me/v7004757/2316a/XUww5gs_jXE.jpg);" class="flex-item2">
      <div class="flex-item">Эротическое бельё</div>
    </li>
    <li style="  background-image: url(http://cs7004.vk.me/v7004757/2316a/XUww5gs_jXE.jpg);" class="flex-item2">
      <div class="flex-item">Эротическое бельё большиx размеров</div>
    </li>
    <li style="  background-image: url(http://cs7004.vk.me/v7004757/2316a/XUww5gs_jXE.jpg);" class="flex-item2">
      <div class="flex-item">Карнавальные костюмы</div>
    </li>
    <li style="  background-image: url(http://cs7004.vk.me/v7004757/2316a/XUww5gs_jXE.jpg);" class="flex-item2">
      <div class="flex-item">Клубная одежда</div>
    </li>
    <li style="  background-image: url(http://cs7004.vk.me/v7004757/2316a/XUww5gs_jXE.jpg);" class="flex-item2">
      <div class="flex-item">Колготки, чулки, леггинсы</div>
    </li>
    <li style="  background-image: url(http://cs7004.vk.me/v7004757/2316a/XUww5gs_jXE.jpg);" class="flex-item2">
      <div class="flex-item">Женская домашняя одежда</div>
    </li>
    <li style="  background-image: url(http://cs7004.vk.me/v7004757/2316a/XUww5gs_jXE.jpg);" class="flex-item2">
      <div class="flex-item">Женское бельё</div>
    </li>
    <li style="  background-image: url(http://cs7004.vk.me/v7004757/2316a/XUww5gs_jXE.jpg);" class="flex-item2">
      <div class="flex-item">Нижнее бельё</div>
    </li>
    <li style="  background-image: url(http://cs7004.vk.me/v7004757/2316a/XUww5gs_jXE.jpg);" class="flex-item2">
      <div class="flex-item">Обувь</div>
    </li>
    <li style="  background-image: url(http://cs7004.vk.me/v7004757/2316a/XUww5gs_jXE.jpg);" class="flex-item2">
      <div class="flex-item">Купальники</div>
    </li>
    <li style="  background-image: url(http://cs7004.vk.me/v7004757/2316a/XUww5gs_jXE.jpg);" class="flex-item2">
      <div class="flex-item">Купальники</div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

P.S. Должно быть как то так http://prntscr.com/b7jfgn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавьте к классу `.flex-item2` свойство `flex-grow:1; margin:10px 5px 0;`